# Convert Ninject ToConstant to Simple Injector Implementation

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, simple-injector

What is the equivalent code in Simpleinjection from this Ninject code using `ToConstant`.

```
Func<Type, IValidator> validatorFactory = type =>
{
    var valType = typeof(Validator<>).MakeGenericType(type);
    return (IValidator)kernel.Get(valType);
};

kernel.Bind<IValidationProvider>().ToConstant(new ValidationProvider(validatorFactory));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RegisterInstance` is the Simple Injector equivalent to Ninject's `ToConstant`:

```
Func<Type, IValidator> validatorFactory = type =>
{
    var valType = typeof(Validator<>).MakeGenericType(type);
    return (IValidator)container.GetInstance(valType);
};

container.RegisterInstance<IValidationProvider>(new ValidationProvider(validatorFactory));
```